# OSX - WebView youtube html5 video getting error

Tags: html, cocoa, video, webview, youtube

I am loading an embedded youtube video into a WebView forcing html5.

```
[webView setMainFrameURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?html5=1",videoId]];
```

It works well until i click play and wait some time i get a strange error in the Logs

```
fragManifold_PushBytes signalled err=-16046 (kFigManifoldError_UnexpectedInitData) (Second 'ftyp' atom encountered) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.232/Prototypes/FormatHandlers/Movie/FigMovieFragmentManifold.c line 1630
```

And the video stops playing. Only way to resume playing is to jump in the timeline at an other point in the video.

I couldn't find anything about this error. Any help ?

Comment: This actually happens only in Yosemite 10.10 and +

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your WebViews user agent using [setCustomUserAgent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setCustomUserAgent:) to `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.6 Safari/600.6.3` (Safaris current user agent on my Mac).

Please note that this will only work with the old [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/) and not the new [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) as of OS X 10.10.